# use truth table to convert formula to CNF form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

```
   p q | ((p→q)∧p)→q
   1 1 | 1 
   1 0 | 1 
   0 1 | 1  
   0 0 | 1
```

I want to convert a formula to CNF form by means of truth tables. However I have a problem I understand that the method is to look for the values of the table of truth that are zero but in this case, what should I do, if all the values are one ?

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

$$p \lor \neg p$$

This is in CNF, since a statement is in CNF iff it is a conjunction of disjunctions of literals (atomic statement or its negation), and this statement can be seen as $1$ conjunct consisting of two disjuncts, where each disjunct is a literal.

Comment: But this does not explain how to get to pv¬p through the truth table.

Comment: @pete Right, I didn;t get this expression using the normal approach since, as you point out, there are no $0$'s.  But that can only happen when the statement is a tautology ... so all you need is some CNF statement that is a tautology, and $p \lor \neg p$ will do the job. So, I got this 'from the truth-table' in so far as that it is an exception.